# How to implement HTTP Conditional Get that uses "If Modified Since"?

Tags: http, get, http-headers, conditional-statements, postman

I have the following `HTTP GET` request:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})  // Accept header
public Response getDetails(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {

    Details details = dao.getDetails(id);
    if (details == null) {
        // account was not found
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity("<detailsNotFound />")
                .build();
    } else {
        details.setLink(new ArrayList<Link>());

        Link linkSelf = new Link();
        linkSelf.setRel("self"); // the "self" relationship
        linkSelf.setUri("/" + id);

        details.getLink().add(linkSelf);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(details).build();
    }
}
```

I am wondering how to implement a **Conditional Get**invoking the **Id-Modified-Since** header with it?

This is the the entities involved:

```
<details>
    <age>32</age>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <timestamp>2018-04-16T00:00:00+01:00</timestamp>
</details>
```

I am using POSTMAN to try this if that makes a difference?

---

**EDIT**

This is now what I have but my main issue is knowing how to compare the if-modified-since header against the Timestamp of the entry in the Database?

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})  // Accept header
public Response getDetails(@PathParam("id") Integer id,@Context HttpHeaders headers) {

    Details details = dao.getDetails(id);

    //Below requests the if-modified-since header
    //Check its not null and prints out the value
    if (headers != null) {
        List<String> ifModifiedSinceHeader = headers.getRequestHeader("if-modified-since");
        if (ifModifiedSinceHeader != null ) {
            for (String ifmodifiedsince : ifModifiedSinceHeader) {
                System.out.print("If-Modified-Since: "+ifmodifiedsince);
            }
        }
    } 

    if (details == null) {
        // account was not found
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity("<detailsNotFound />")
                .build();
    } else {

        details.setLink(new ArrayList<Link>());

        Link linkSelf = new Link();
        linkSelf.setRel("self"); // the "self" relationship
        linkSelf.setUri("/" + id);

        details.getLink().add(linkSelf);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(details).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the data isn't newer than the `if-modified-since` timestamp, you just return a `304` response with no body.  Otherwise you return the new data.

Comment: @Joe my issue is not knowing where to put it?

Comment: @Joe I mean where do I put the `If-Modified-Since` header

Comment: `If-Modified-Since` comes in with the request (browser or other client).  Your code will have to extract that header to get the date value to compare to the server data.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? I can't find examples anywhere!

Comment: 2nd hit on google. guess you didn't look very hard.  https://varvy.com/ifmodified.html  and 5th hit: https://www.logicbig.com/quick-info/web/last-modified-and-if-modified-since.html

Comment: I meant a code example? there's no code example there?

Comment: @Joe or anyone, I have added an edit to the POST and wonder could you assist with the final part